# I'm a bot (or at least you say so). How do I post?

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha

Apparently I'm a bot, or I'm detected as such.

I cannot even prove you wrong, since the captcha I'm supposed to solve won't appear.  Unfortunately I cannot give more details, since I just see a picture of a robot laying on the ground, and I don't get any detail on what's going on in the first place.

Any suggestion?

Comment: We just had a brief outage, it's possible you were hitting an error page. Are you still just a robot?

Comment: Oh, well, if it is an outage, than I'll just try again tomorrow.  Thanks.

Comment: The outage should be over (https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1057385414770769926), are you still seeing errors?

Comment: Let me try again...

Comment: Ok, now I could just log in plain, and edit a post of mine.

Comment: Well, I guess I can just close this question then.  Thanks :)

Comment: You have to battle the world champion in Go, if you win you are either a man, or a good bot.  If you lose, well that's a corner case.

Answer (score 4):

There was a bad build that was impacting the display [of some questions](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1057385414770769926). The build was rolled back and pages should be loading normally again.

We're still investigating the bug that caused the problem in the first place, but things should be working fine now.

Comment: "Some questions"... more like every main and meta question, as well as the ask question page on main and meta.

Comment: @TinyGiant It affected logged-in users only. It took a bit to ascertain exactly what failed here. Statistically, it affected few question hits (hence the "some"), but what the delineation wasn't immediately clear (getting everything back up ASAP was priority). I'm working on rolling out an update with a fix in place now.